# cuda.memcpy_dtoh too slow. Looking for way to optimise it

Tags: python, cuda, dask

I am trying to implement a Odd-Even Transposition Sort using CUDA to help to do sort_values() by multiply key columns on data in Dask dataframe.  The below code works well, especially when the NumberOfSample is set to a small number.

However when NumberOfSample is set to something larger, cuda.memcpy_dtoh is taking predominantly most of the time.  Output of timestamps after each step are shown below.  Is there any way to speed up or optimise cuda.memcpy_dtoh?

I would equally appreciate if someone can advise a way to do sorting by multiple columns on large data set in dask dataframe, which pandas dataframe cannot hold or have enough memory to do.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import dask.bag as db

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import InvestmentAnalytics.CUDA.CUDAPathSetting

def CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns(df, by, ascending = True, GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE = 32*32):
    ErrorCode = 0
    if GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE <= 16:
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z = GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X = 1
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y = 1
    else:
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z = 16
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y = int( GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE / 16)
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X = 1
    if GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y > 8:
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X = int( GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y / 8)
        GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y = 8
    
    df_by = df[by]
    
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        df_by_matrix = df_by.to_numpy()
    else:
        df_by_matrix = np.asarray(df_by)
    df_by_matrix = df_by_matrix.astype(np.float32)
    df_by_matrix = df_by_matrix.copy(order="C")
    
    first_dimension_size = len(df_by_matrix)
    second_dimension_size = len(df_by_matrix[0])
    print('first_dimension_size is ' + str(first_dimension_size) + ' and second_dimension_size is ' + str(second_dimension_size))
    
    sorted_index_matrix = np.arange(0,first_dimension_size)

    debug_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(int(100 * 4))
    
    odd_even_indicator = np.int32(0)
    thread_done_count = np.int32(0)
    swap_done_count = np.int32(0)
    sorting_done_indicator = np.int32(0)
    
    df_by_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(df_by_matrix.nbytes)
    sorted_index_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(sorted_index_matrix.nbytes)
    odd_even_indicator_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(odd_even_indicator.nbytes)
    thread_done_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(thread_done_count.nbytes)
    swap_done_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(swap_done_count.nbytes)
    sorting_done_indicator_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(sorting_done_indicator.nbytes)

    cuda.memcpy_htod(df_by_matrix_gpu, df_by_matrix)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(sorted_index_matrix_gpu, sorted_index_matrix)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(odd_even_indicator_gpu, odd_even_indicator)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(thread_done_count_gpu, thread_done_count)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(swap_done_count_gpu, swap_done_count)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(sorting_done_indicator_gpu, sorting_done_indicator)
   
    mod = SourceModule("""
      #include <cstdlib>
    
      __global__ void dataframe_sort_by_cuda(int first_dimension_size, int second_dimension_size, int GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X, int GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y, int GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z, int ErrorCode, int *odd_even_indicator, int *thread_done_count, int *swap_done_count, int *sorting_done_indicator, float *df_by_matrix, int *sorted_index_matrix, float *debug_matrix)
      {
        int loop_count, max_loop, thread_Index, Total_Thread_count, sort_swap_index, new_thread_done_count, new_swap_done_count, odd_even_indicator_to_run, swap_index_temp, accumulated_no_swap_count;
        float swap_temp;
        loop_count = 0;
        max_loop = 9;
        ErrorCode = 0;
        Total_Thread_count = GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X * GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y * GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z - 1;
        thread_Index = threadIdx.x * GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y * GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z + threadIdx.y * GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z + threadIdx.z;
        
        if (thread_Index == 0) {
            accumulated_no_swap_count = 0;
            while (thread_done_count[0] < Total_Thread_count || accumulated_no_swap_count >= 2) {
                    while (thread_done_count[0] < Total_Thread_count) { 
                      __nanosleep(10);
                    }
                    if (swap_done_count[0] > 0) {
                        accumulated_no_swap_count = 0;
                        swap_done_count[0] = 0;
                        odd_even_indicator[0] = (odd_even_indicator[0] + 1) % 2;
                        thread_done_count[0] = 0;
                    } else {
                        accumulated_no_swap_count++;
                    }
            }
            sorting_done_indicator[0] = 1;
        } else {
            while (sorting_done_indicator[0] <= 0) {
              odd_even_indicator_to_run = odd_even_indicator[0];
              sort_swap_index = (thread_Index - 1) * 2 + odd_even_indicator_to_run;
              
              while (sort_swap_index +  1 < first_dimension_size) {
                  for (int i=0; i<second_dimension_size; i++) {
                    if (df_by_matrix[(sort_swap_index + 1) * second_dimension_size + i] > df_by_matrix[sort_swap_index * second_dimension_size + i]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (df_by_matrix[(sort_swap_index + 1) * second_dimension_size + i] < df_by_matrix[sort_swap_index * second_dimension_size + i]) {
                      new_swap_done_count = atomicAdd(swap_done_count,1);
                      for (int j=0; j<second_dimension_size; j++) {
                        swap_temp = df_by_matrix[(sort_swap_index + 1) * second_dimension_size + j];
                        df_by_matrix[(sort_swap_index + 1) * second_dimension_size + j] = df_by_matrix[sort_swap_index * second_dimension_size + j];
                        df_by_matrix[sort_swap_index * second_dimension_size + j] = swap_temp;
                      }
                      swap_index_temp = sorted_index_matrix[sort_swap_index + 1];
                      sorted_index_matrix[sort_swap_index + 1] = sorted_index_matrix[sort_swap_index];
                      sorted_index_matrix[sort_swap_index] = swap_index_temp;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  sort_swap_index = sort_swap_index + (Total_Thread_count * 2);
              }
              
              new_thread_done_count = atomicAdd(thread_done_count,1);
              while (sorting_done_indicator[0] <= 0 && odd_even_indicator_to_run == odd_even_indicator[0]) { 
                 __nanosleep(100);
              }
              odd_even_indicator_to_run = odd_even_indicator[0];
              sort_swap_index = (thread_Index - 1) * 2 + odd_even_indicator_to_run;
            }
        }
      }
      """)
          
    func = mod.get_function("dataframe_sort_by_cuda")
    func(np.int32(first_dimension_size), np.int32(second_dimension_size), np.int32(GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X), np.int32(GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y), np.int32(GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z), np.int32(ErrorCode), odd_even_indicator_gpu, thread_done_count_gpu, swap_done_count_gpu, sorting_done_indicator_gpu, df_by_matrix_gpu, sorted_index_matrix_gpu, debug_matrix_gpu, block=(GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_X,GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y,GPU_CORE_BLOCK_SIZE_Z))

    print('after running dataframe_sort_by_cuda at ' + str(datetime.now()))

    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(sorted_index_matrix, sorted_index_matrix_gpu)

    print('after memcpy_dtoh sorted_index_matrix at ' + str(datetime.now()))

    df_by_matrix_gpu.free()
    sorted_index_matrix_gpu.free()
    debug_matrix_gpu.free()
    
    print('after freeing GPU memory, before creating df_sorted_index at ' + str(datetime.now()))

    df_sorted_index = pd.DataFrame(sorted_index_matrix, columns=['sorted_index'])
    df_sorted_index['rank'] = list(range(0, len(df_sorted_index)))
    
    print('before running sorting of df_sorted_index at ' + str(datetime.now()))
    
    df_sorted_index = df_sorted_index.sort_values(by=['sorted_index'], ascending=True, inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    print('after running sorting of df_sorted_index at ' + str(datetime.now()))
    
    df['rank'] = df_sorted_index['rank']
    df = df.sort_values(by=['rank'], ascending=True, inplace=False).drop(columns=['rank'])  

    print('after running sorting of df at ' + str(datetime.now()))
      
    return df

NumberOfSample = 500000
NumberOfPartition = 2
SortByColumn = ['rand3', 'rand1', 'rand2']

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame("Happy", index=list(range(0,NumberOfSample)), columns=['x']) 
pandas_df['rand1'] = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=NumberOfSample) / 10
pandas_df['rand2'] = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=NumberOfSample) / 10
pandas_df['rand3'] = 1

print('pandas_df with constant value is')
print(pandas_df)  

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=NumberOfPartition)

print('ddf before sorting is with len ' + str(len(ddf)))
print(ddf.head(NumberOfSample, NumberOfPartition))

print('before running CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns at ' + str(datetime.now()))

ddf_sorted = CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns(ddf, by=SortByColumn)

print('after running CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns at ' + str(datetime.now()))

print('ddf_sorted after sorting is with len ' + str(len(ddf)))
print(ddf_sorted.head(NumberOfSample, NumberOfPartition))
```

```
before running CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns at 2022-11-12 22:32:20.317164
after running dataframe_sort_by_cuda at 2022-11-12 22:32:23.801310
after memcpy_dtoh sorted_index_matrix at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.767990
after freeing GPU memory, before creating df_sorted_index at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.767990
before running sorting of df_sorted_index at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.860404
after running sorting of df_sorted_index at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.908558
after running sorting of df at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.971194
after running CUDADaskSortByFloatColumns at 2022-11-12 23:04:40.971194
```

Comment: The CUDA kernel launch is asynchronous so you are getting confused by your timing method. This is a common question.

Comment: which means most of the time was actually spent inside the cuda (those c++ code) calculation?

Comment: Maybe. You are measuring times of sending data to GPU. You need something like CudaDeviceSynchronize (cuda.driver.synchronize?). And it is more visual to use time differences than timestamps :)